ArcGIS Earth 1.10 Not Opening for Specific User (Windows 11)
I'm a local IT admin for my company. I have an end user who cannot open ArcGIS Earth 1.10. I've checked the registry, verified the computer and anti-virus programs are fully updated as the company's overall IT managers permit. When trying to run the program on their account, I've watched it boot up in the Task Manager where I saw it get "suspended" and then crash. I've checked the logs too. Those showed me the user profile wasn't establishing a session, but it still proceeded to open the program until it suddenly closed.
Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing?
I can't even attempt repairing it from the appwiz.cpl window, considering the repair tool can't find the .msi file.
